# How to send an arbitrary string via an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc

I'd like to send arbitrary strings (not paths or URLs) between two of my company's Android apps, but the Intent data is a URI. Presently I'm concerned with starting an Activity, but in some cases it would be nice to be able to send a query and receive a response without starting an Activity. So:

- How should I send any arbitrary string when Intent wants a URI?
- What other communication mechanisms could I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary string to an intent by using extras on the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra(SOME_STATIC_NAME_VALUE, "your_arbitrary_string");
```

There are many options for extra's, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

To retrieve the string in your receiving activity, use

```
intent.getExtras().getString(SOME_STATIC_NAME_VALUE)
```

Or the appropriate getter for whatever value you set on the extra.

Answer (score 7):

For `Intent intent = new Intent();`, you can use `intent.putExtra(String name, String value);` to store a `String` `value` that is keyed to `name`. In your called activity, use `intent.getStringExtra(name);` to retrieve the value.

Comment: `Intent` doesn't have a method `getExtra(...)`. Your answer should be to use `getStringExtra(name)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Was in a bit of a rush, but that hardly excuses giving an incorrect method name.

Comment: No problem. I always have to think twice about the method names for `Intent` as it has multiple `putExtra(...)` methods for every type that it can accept but each `get...` method is specific for data type - slightly confusing to remember which way round it works. Other than that, your answer was sound.